# Are you making this up?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

**Man**: But do you make enough money for everything you do?

**Woman**: Just enough. I make do.

**Man**: So do I. I make do as well. I get by. I get up in the morning. I get dressed. I get on the bus. I get off the bus. I get to work.

**Woman**: I don't get it.

**Man**: You don't get what?

**Woman**: I don't understand. I don't get what you do. What do you do?

**Man**: I make money.

**Woman**: You make money? Are you **making this up**?

**Man**: No. It's true. I'm not making this up. That's all I do all day long. I make lots and lots of money.

**Woman**: Get out of here.

---

What does "Are you **making this up**" mean?

Comment: It means *to say something that's completely false*.

Comment: The assertion *entirely answerable with a dictionary* might fall into a gray zone more commonly than many of us may immediately think. ELLs are often unequipped to transform text they see or hear into the text they may need to search for to obtain a definition online in a straightforward way (e.g., "making this up" > "[to] make [it/something] up". My top google results on "define making this up" returned at top only "(chiefly Br) to become friendly again after being angry." Further: If someone's browser isn't set to the same default settings that native speakers' often are, another obstacle.

Comment: If there is something you still don't understand about the phrase, you should make it clear in your question. The picture you added didn't seem to help in any way clarify the context.

Comment: @rezaellstack t has been observed before, but the text that you are using is very very poor.  It contains lots of examples of unnatural conversations and odd English. I strongly encourage you to find a new textbook, or talk to your teachers about it. A book this bad can actually confuse you.

Answer (score 1):

If you *make something up* you're saying things that you've imagined, they're not based in truth and facts. Either you're lying and knowingly inventing things that are false, or you're saying things that you have no reason to believe, and if they actually turn out to be true then it would just be a coincidence, because you didn't actually *know* what you were talking about.

So the woman is trying to understand what the man does for his job, and all he'll say is "I make money" - it not clear if he's trying to say he literally creates or produces money, or if he's saying "I earn money" while refusing to give any detail about what work he does. The woman is getting frustrated with his lack of answers, and is asking him if he's just *making the whole thing up* - if he's just spinning a fantasy story and stringing her along.